# I want to have multiple maps in layout view, based on selected spatial data. Is this possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layouts

I have a point data set with meta data. Based on this meta data I want to display the selected data in two or more different layout view windows in ArcMap 10.3 at the same time. Is this possible?

Comment: By "layout view windows" do you mean dataframes or something else?

Comment: I mean Data frames

Comment: Then yes it is possible. Give it a shot. When you open layout view after adding a new (second ... third) data frame, they will be in your layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new data frames to your map and display your point data in different ways on each data frame. Move the data frames on your page that you can see all frames simultaneously in THE layout view. But there are not more than the one layout view window.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful!
Is it possible to further share this map layout to a portal?